Adding features to Gutenberg without theme.json
I am using a non-block theme for my website and am using Gutenberg for writing posts. I want to extend Gutenberg's functionality by adding the image lightbox feature. So I added a theme.json file to the non-block theme and left it empty, exept for
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/theme.json",
    "version": 2,
    "settings": {
        "blocks": {
            "core/image": {
                "lightbox": {
                    "enabled": true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "styles": {},
    "templateParts": [],
    "customTemplates": []
}

Still, the theme.json file f.ex. adds underlines to links that I don't want. How could I setup the theme.json file so that it doesn't do anthing at all, so that I can use it for adding functionality to Gutenberg?
Thanks!
